# Google Sheets: Data Validation for date is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, using Google App Script I've set a data validation based on date criteria like below

[image]

Data validation works fine for text values but it's not giving error popup for numeric values:

[image]

[image]

I would like to display error popup when user enters invalid date.

Any help or suggestion would be great!

Comment: See Alexandre's suggestion below. However, I will add to it. Google sheets sees 12/31/99 as having the year 1999, not 2099. For 2099, you would need to specifically set the year to 2099 (not just 99). Keep this in mind moving forward.

Comment: @ErikTyler, it's 12/31/9999 not 12/31/99. Last two characters are not visible in the screenshot. Also can you please let me know if there is a way to combine both "is valid date" and "between" data validation?

Comment: I don't believe Google Sheets will recognize the year 9999 as a valid year (and therefore will not recognize 12/31/9999 as a valid date). You should be able to combine what you want using the "custom formula is" with a combination of AND, ISDATE, DATEVALUE, >= and <=.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try  changing the criteria to IS VALID DATE

[image]

Comment: It worked, but is there a way to set multiple data validations, one for valid date and another for between validation?

Comment: Set the Data Validation to Custom Formula and use something like this (assuming your date is in C7. Replace the dates to be in the range you need:. In the example, is accepting dates between 01-Jan-2000 and 31 Dec-2010 : 
 
 =AND(ISDATE(C7),C7>DATE(2000,1,1);C7<DATE(2010,12,31))